# How to get the URL of the image using jquery in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

I am developing a small lightbox wordpress plugin in which if a user clicks an image the image should appear in the lightbox. How can i identify URL of the image in which the user clicks, so it will be useful in showing the image in lightbox. Is this can be done in jquery? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this

```
$("img").click(function() {
    var img_path = $(this).attr('src');
})
```

**EDIT**

change

```
data: dataString,
```

to

```
data: 'img_path='+img_path,
```

and you will be able to access the image path in lightbox.php like this

```
$image_path = $_POST['image_path'];
```

Comment: is there any way to pass this **img_path** value to php variable?

Comment: @raj: how about using `ajax` ?

Comment: `$("img").click(function() {
    var img_path = $(this).attr('src');
 $.ajax({
 type:'POST',
    url: 'lightbox.php',
    dataType: 'HTML',
 data: dataString,
    success: function(data){
 
    }
});
});`this is the ajax i tried but cant get it

Comment: Ya i tried but not working. Is there any changes to be made on `success: function(data){ }`

Comment: is it possible to append this `img_path` to **img** tag like this <img src"value of img_path here">

Comment: Use ajax only if you have to do anything on server ( like grab the image name from DB). Unless just use simple jQuery to change the `src` of the next image like this `$('.new_img').attr('src',img_path)`

Answer (score 1):

Getting the image url is easy.

```
$(function() {

  $('img').on('click', function( event ) {
    var source = this.src;    
    console.log( source );
  });

});
```